# Mule threading profile is not restricting the thread count

Tags: multithreading, mule

I am using mule 3.1.1. I use the following configuration in my flow for threading profile.

```
<configuration>
 <default-dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="50" maxBufferSize="30" maxThreadsIdle="50" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
     <default-receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="25" maxBufferSize="15" maxThreadsIdle="25" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
</configuration>
```

Under load tests, the live thread count is going beyond 75 and reaching almost 170. I am looking at thread count through jconsole. I am not quite sure if this is normal.Was expecting the count to stay within 75. Can someone please help me understand the behaviour.

Comment: This is per connector: so if you have more than one connector, you'll get n times 75 threads.

Comment: Thanks David.My flow has one HTTP inbound endpoint, two synchronous outbound endpoints- one HTTP, one JDBC ,two asynchronous one-way outbound endpoints(both vm). My understanding is default-receiver-threading profile will be applicable to all inbound endpoints and all other endpoints which take part in the synchronous call. Basically for synchronous calls, it is just the receiver thread which will complete the task end-end. Whereas for all the asynchronous endpoints like VM, dispatcher thread will come into action. Am I correct?

Comment: This is not entirely true: the processing strategy of the flow can also influence that, also one-way outbound endpoints can execute with their own threads. If you output the thread names in the logs, you'll clearly see what's actually happening. FTR we discuss the non-obvious aspect of threading in chapter 2 of Mule in Action, 2nd ed.

Comment: thanks again, is there a formula or a standard way to define the threading profile. Basically I do not have concurrent request exceeding more than 40. As I mentioned, I have 2 asynchronous flows, and one main receiver flow, In that case what is the best way to define thread profile for receiver and dispatcher threads.Assuming its a single core processor,do you have any comments on my config?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance for an in-depth discussion about threading in Mule, including formulas for calculating thread counts for the different pools in use in Mule.

Comment: The mule doc does have the formula, however, think it does not clearly explain how to calculate maxActive for asynchronous flows. Also m bit unclear on default configuration for flow threads. There is default-receiver-profile and default-dispatcher profile.But what abt default-flow-profile?I believe these parts are not explained properly in the documentation or I may b m totally missing something. I calculated the receiver thread profile and then bumped up the dispatcher threads by double of receiver's configuration as I have 2 async flows writing to DB.Is it rgt approach? Thanks for your help